# Sorting on a page with two p:dataTables results in NullpointerException

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page that usually displays a `dataTable` I created, and under certain circumstances two such tables are displayed:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="viewMode" value="#{backendBean.viewMode}"/>
            <f:viewAction action="#{backendBean.init}"  />
    </f:metadata>
    <h:form id="frmTables" styleClass="frmTablesStyle">
    
                <customTableClass:customTable
                        viewModeName = "#{backendBean.viewMode.name()}"
                        data= "#{backendBean.dataAttribute}" />
    
                <c:if test="#{backendBean.viewMode.name() == 'FOREIGN'}">
    
                    <arbeitsauftrag:arbeitsauftragUebersichtTabelle
                            viewModeName = "FOREIGN"
                            data= "#{backendBean.otherDataAttribute}" />
                </c:if>
    
     </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

The tables work fine, however, when I display BOTH tables at the same time and try to sort the FIRST table, I get a nullpointerexception with this stacktrace:

```
Sep 01, 2021 9:53:43 AM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
INFO: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.decode(SortFeature.java:81)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:832)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:281)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:835)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer.visitTree(UINamingContainer.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:143)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:927)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:93)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:238)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:237)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at at.akooe.filter.Log4jFilter.doFilter(Log4jFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:123)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:180)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2536)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2525)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Sep 01, 2021 9:53:43 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase execute
WARNING: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:273)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:143)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:927)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:93)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:238)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:237)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at at.akooe.filter.Log4jFilter.doFilter(Log4jFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:123)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:180)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2536)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2525)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.decode(SortFeature.java:81)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:832)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:281)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:835)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer.visitTree(UINamingContainer.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266)
    ... 55 more

Sep 01, 2021 9:53:43 AM org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler logException
SEVERE: FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/error/error.xhtml' will be shown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.decode(SortFeature.java:81)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:832)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:281)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:835)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer.visitTree(UINamingContainer.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:143)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:927)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:93)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:238)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:237)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at at.akooe.filter.Log4jFilter.doFilter(Log4jFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:123)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:180)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2536)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2525)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is the relevant code frome the backing bean:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{entityRepository}")
    @Getter @Setter private EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Getter @Setter private LazyDataModel<Data> dataAttribute;
    @Getter @Setter private LazyDataModel<Data> otherDataAttribute;

    public void init() {

        data= new LazyDataModel<Data>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public List<data> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
                CustomFilter filterParameter = createFilter(filters);
                setRowCount(entityRepository.getCount(filterParameter));

                return entityRepository.getDataOverview(filterParameter,  (first / pageSize) + 1, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder);
            }

            @Override
            public Object getRowKey(Data data) {
                return data.getId();
            }

            @Override
            public data getRowData(String rowKey) {
                return entityRepository.getDataById(Long.parseLong(rowKey));
            }
        };

        if (viewMode == ViewMode.FOREIGN) {

            otherDataAttribute = new LazyDataModel<Data>() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

                @Override
                public List<data> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

                CustomFilter filterParameter = createFilter(filters);

                setRowCount(entityRepository.getCount(filterParameter));

                return entityRepository.getDataOverview(filterParameter,  (first / pageSize) + 1, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder);
                }

                @Override
                public Object getRowKey(Data data) {
                    return data.getId();
                }

                @Override
                public Data getRowData(String rowKey) {
                    return entityRepository.getArbeitsauftragById(Long.parseLong(rowKey));
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public CustomFilter createFilter(Map<String, Object> filters) {
        //...Create Filterobject
    }
```

It is always the first table displayed that fail on sorting, the second table always works fine. Also, the `load()` method is not envoked before the nullpointerexception is thrown. Whats going on here?

Comment: Make sure to give them unique `id`, `widgetVar` `var` values so don't use `var="row"` for both. I have seen that screw up multiple datatables on the same page in the same `h:form`.  The other thing to try is put each in its own `h:form`.

Comment: Assigning unique id and widgetVar solved the problem! Thanks a lot! If you write a an answer I could accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to give each table a unique `id` and `widgetVar` so you don't have collisions between the javascript running for each table.